# "Unspecified error" when trying to create a table from SSMS 2005 on a SQL Server 2008 DB

Tags: sql-server-2005, sql-server-2008

I have just installed SP3 for SSMS 2005 so that I can connect to 2008 databases.
I can now connect fine and even create databases, but I get "Unspecified error" when I try to create a new table.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried a standard [`CREATE TABLE`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174979.aspx) script and avoid using the designer?

SSMS (and SQL tools in general) are not *usually* forward compatible, but YMMV of course. So SQL Server 2008 SSMS will manage SQL Server 2005 engines but not vice versa...

Why did you install SQL 2005 SP3 to manage SQL Server 2008 anyway?

Comment: I already had SQL 2005 and I'd had difficulty installing 2008 on this machine about 6 months ago so I thought I'd give SP3 a go first.

Comment: @Pete: This link backs up my answer: you need the correct version of tools for the engien you want to administer http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/sqlexpress/thread/111214f7-46c3-45b9-8b99-47abaef0cce5